# Understanding Ord and PartialOrd macros

Tags: rust, macros, traits

So, I have this working code:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::fmt;

mod errors;
use errors::VersionParseError;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Version {
    epoch: u64,
    version: String,
    release: u64,
}

impl Version {
    pub fn new(epoch: u64, version: impl Into<String>, release: u64) -> Self {
        Self {
            epoch,
            version: version.into(),
            release,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_string(version: impl Into<String>) -> Result<Self, VersionParseError> {
        let (epoch, version) = parse_epoch(&version.into())?;
        let (version, release) = parse_release(&version)?;
        Ok(Self::new(epoch, version, release))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Version {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match self.epoch.cmp(&other.epoch) {
            Ordering::Equal => match compare(&self.version, &other.version) {
                Ordering::Equal => Some(self.release.cmp(&other.release)),
                result => Some(result),
            },
            result => Some(result),
        }
    }
}

impl Ord for Version {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Version {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        if self.epoch == 0 {
            write!(f, "{}-{}", self.version, self.release)
        } else {
            write!(f, "{}:{}-{}", self.epoch, self.version, self.release)
        }
    }
}

fn parse_epoch(version: &String) -> Result<(u64, String), VersionParseError> {
    match version.split_once(':') {
        Some((epoch, remainder)) => match epoch.parse::<u64>() {
            Ok(epoch) => Ok((epoch, String::from(remainder))),
            Err(_) => Err(VersionParseError::InvalidEpoch),
        },
        None => Ok((0, String::from(version))),
    }
}

fn parse_release(version: &String) -> Result<(String, u64), VersionParseError> {
    match version.split_once('-') {
        Some((remainder, release)) => match release.parse::<u64>() {
            Ok(release) => Ok((String::from(remainder), release)),
            Err(_) => Err(VersionParseError::InvalidRelease),
        },
        None => Err(VersionParseError::NoReleaseSpecified),
    }
}

fn compare(lhs: &String, rhs: &String) -> Ordering {
    let l_segments = segments(lhs);
    let r_segments = segments(rhs);

    for (l_segment, r_segment) in l_segments.iter().zip(r_segments.iter()) {
        match compare_segments(l_segment, r_segment) {
            Ordering::Greater => {
                return Ordering::Greater;
            }
            Ordering::Less => {
                return Ordering::Less;
            }
            _ => {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    l_segments.len().cmp(&r_segments.len())
}

fn segments(version: &String) -> Vec<String> {
    normalize(version)
        .split(".")
        .map(|segment| String::from(segment))
        .collect()
}

fn normalize(version: &String) -> String {
    version
        .chars()
        .map(|chr| if chr.is_alphanumeric() { chr } else { '.' })
        .collect()
}

fn compare_segments(lhs: &str, rhs: &str) -> Ordering {
    let l_blocks = blocks(lhs);
    let r_blocks = blocks(rhs);
    let mut last: usize = 0;

    for (index, (l_block, r_block)) in l_blocks.iter().zip(r_blocks.iter()).enumerate() {
        last = index;

        match compare_blocks(l_block, r_block) {
            Ordering::Equal => {
                continue;
            }
            ordering => {
                return ordering;
            }
        }
    }

    match l_blocks
        .iter()
        .nth(last + 1)
        .unwrap_or(&String::new())
        .chars()
        .nth(0)
    {
        Some(chr) => {
            if chr.is_ascii_digit() {
                Ordering::Greater
            } else {
                Ordering::Less
            }
        }
        None => match r_blocks
            .iter()
            .nth(last + 1)
            .unwrap_or(&String::new())
            .chars()
            .nth(0)
        {
            Some(chr) => {
                if chr.is_ascii_digit() {
                    Ordering::Less
                } else {
                    Ordering::Greater
                }
            }
            None => Ordering::Equal,
        },
    }
}

fn blocks(segment: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut block = String::new();

    for chr in segment.chars() {
        match block.chars().nth(0) {
            Some(current) => {
                if same_type(&chr, &current) {
                    block.push(chr);
                } else {
                    result.push(block.clone());
                    block.clear();
                    block.push(chr);
                }
            }
            None => {
                block.push(chr);
            }
        }
    }

    if !block.is_empty() {
        result.push(block.clone());
    }

    result
}

fn same_type(lhs: &char, rhs: &char) -> bool {
    lhs.is_ascii_digit() == rhs.is_ascii_digit()
}

fn compare_blocks(lhs: &String, rhs: &String) -> Ordering {
    if lhs == rhs {
        return Ordering::Equal;
    }

    let l_is_number = lhs.chars().all(|chr| chr.is_ascii_digit());
    let r_is_number = rhs.chars().all(|chr| chr.is_ascii_digit());

    if l_is_number && r_is_number {
        compare_alpha(lhs, rhs)
    } else if l_is_number && !r_is_number {
        Ordering::Greater
    } else if !l_is_number && r_is_number {
        Ordering::Less
    } else {
        lhs.cmp(rhs)
    }
}

fn compare_alpha(lhs: &str, rhs: &str) -> Ordering {
    let lhs = lhs.trim_start_matches('0');
    let rhs = rhs.trim_start_matches('0');

    match lhs.len().cmp(&rhs.len()) {
        Ordering::Equal => lhs.cmp(&rhs),
        ordering => ordering,
    }
}
```

I also tried to get rid of the presumably redundant implementation of `Ord` and use the appropriate macro to derive the default.
However, when I remove the implementation of `Ord` and add the macro to the `derive` list, the behaviour of the comparison operations (`<`, `==`, `>`) changes.
Why is that? What is the default implementation of `cmp()` derived by the `Ord` macro?
I could not find it in the standard library, since it is a compiler built-in.

Since the implementation of `partial_cmp()` is complete, I also tried to implement `Ord` with `cmp()` analog to the current `partial_cmp` (except the `Option`) and derive `PartialOrd` with the appropriate macro. However, this also changes, i.e. breaks the behaviour of the comparison operators.

So my question is how `Ord` and `PartialOrd` play together and wether I really must implement both traits manually as I did above?

*Addendum:*
Here's the complete project:

`Cargo.toml`:

````ini
`Cargo.toml`:
```toml
[package]
name = "librucman"
version = "0.1.1"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

[dev-dependencies]
once_cell = "*"
````

`./tests/vercmp.rs`:

```rust
use librucman::version::Version;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

mod common;
use common::{load_version_pair, EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, LESS_THAN, VERSIONS};

#[test]
fn version_parsing() {
    for (string, version) in VERSIONS.iter() {
        assert_eq!(*version, Version::from_string(*string).unwrap());
    }
}

#[test]
fn version_comparison() {
    for (lhs, rhs) in EQUAL.map(load_version_pair) {
        assert_eq!(lhs, rhs);
        assert_eq!(Ordering::Equal, lhs.cmp(&rhs))
    }

    for (lhs, rhs) in GREATER_THAN.map(load_version_pair) {
        assert!(lhs > rhs);
        assert_eq!(Ordering::Greater, lhs.cmp(&rhs))
    }

    for (lhs, rhs) in LESS_THAN.map(load_version_pair) {
        assert!(lhs < rhs);
        assert_eq!(Ordering::Less, lhs.cmp(&rhs))
    }
}
```

`./tests/common/mod.rs`:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use std::collections::HashMap;

use librucman::version::Version;

pub static VERSIONS: Lazy<HashMap<&'static str, Version>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    HashMap::from([
        (
            "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3",
            Version::new(1, "2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f", 3),
        ),
        ("2.28.3-1", Version::new(0, "2.28.3", 1)),
        ("2.3.2.post1-1", Version::new(0, "2.3.2.post1", 1)),
        ("20220913.f09bebf-1", Version::new(0, "20220913.f09bebf", 1)),
        (
            "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4",
            Version::new(2, "2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5", 4),
        ),
        ("4.3-3", Version::new(0, "4.3", 3)),
        (
            "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3",
            Version::new(0, "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4", 3),
        ),
        ("7.4.3-1", Version::new(0, "7.4.3", 1)),
        ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", Version::new(0, "r2322+3aebf69d", 1)),
        ("0.4.4-1", Version::new(0, "0.4.4", 1)),
        ("2.14.2-363", Version::new(0, "2.14.2", 363)),
    ])
});

pub const EQUAL: [(&str, &str); 10] = [
    ("0.4.4-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("4.3-3", "4.3-3"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
];

pub const LESS_THAN: [(&str, &str); 48] = [
    ("0.4.4-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("0.4.4-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("4.3-3", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("4.3-3", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("4.3-3", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("4.3-3", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("4.3-3", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("r2322+3aebf69d-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4"),
    ("41.1-2", "42beta+r14+g2d9d76c-2"),
    ("1.14.50-1", "2022d-1"),
    ("5.15.6+kde+r50-1", "5.15.6+kde+r177-1"),
];

pub const GREATER_THAN: [(&str, &str); 52] = [
    ("0.4.4-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("2.3.2.post1-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "4.3-3"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("4.3-3", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("4.3-3", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("4.3-3", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("4.3-3", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("2.28.3-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "1:2.3.5+r3+gd9d61d87f-3"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "4.3-3"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("2:2.06.r322.gd9b4638c5-4", "20220913.f09bebf-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "4.3-3"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("7.4.3-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "0.4.4-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "2.3.2.post1-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "4.3-3"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "2.28.3-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "r2322+3aebf69d-1"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "6.04.pre2.r11.gbf6db5b4-3"),
    ("20220913.f09bebf-1", "7.4.3-1"),
    ("1.4rc5-14", "1.0.3.1-6"),
    ("2.38.0-2", "2.038ro+1.058it+1.018var-1"),
    ("1.21.0-1", "1.3-1"),
    ("0.8.2-5", "0.8-5"),
    ("3.2.13-1", "3.02a09-5"),
    ("9.0.2-1", "9.0p1-1"),
    ("3.2.2-2", "3.02a09-5"),
];

pub fn load_version_pair((lhs, rhs): (&str, &str)) -> (Version, Version) {
    (
        Version::from_string(lhs).unwrap(),
        Version::from_string(rhs).unwrap(),
    )
}
```

`./src/version/errors.rs`:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum VersionParseError {
    InvalidEpoch,
    InvalidRelease,
    NoReleaseSpecified,
}

impl VersionParseError {
    pub fn to_string(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            Self::InvalidEpoch => "invalid epoch",
            Self::InvalidRelease => "invalid release",
            Self::NoReleaseSpecified => "no release specified",
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for VersionParseError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string())
    }
}
```

`./src/version.rs`:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::fmt;

mod errors;
use errors::VersionParseError;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Version {
    epoch: u64,
    version: String,
    release: u64,
}

impl Version {
    pub fn new(epoch: u64, version: impl Into<String>, release: u64) -> Self {
        Self {
            epoch,
            version: version.into(),
            release,
        }
    }

    pub fn from_string(version: impl Into<String>) -> Result<Self, VersionParseError> {
        let (epoch, version) = parse_epoch(&version.into())?;
        let (version, release) = parse_release(&version)?;
        Ok(Self::new(epoch, version, release))
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Version {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match self.epoch.cmp(&other.epoch) {
            Ordering::Equal => match compare(&self.version, &other.version) {
                Ordering::Equal => Some(self.release.cmp(&other.release)),
                result => Some(result),
            },
            result => Some(result),
        }
    }
}

impl Ord for Version {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Version {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        if self.epoch == 0 {
            write!(f, "{}-{}", self.version, self.release)
        } else {
            write!(f, "{}:{}-{}", self.epoch, self.version, self.release)
        }
    }
}

fn parse_epoch(version: &String) -> Result<(u64, String), VersionParseError> {
    match version.split_once(':') {
        Some((epoch, remainder)) => match epoch.parse::<u64>() {
            Ok(epoch) => Ok((epoch, String::from(remainder))),
            Err(_) => Err(VersionParseError::InvalidEpoch),
        },
        None => Ok((0, String::from(version))),
    }
}

fn parse_release(version: &String) -> Result<(String, u64), VersionParseError> {
    match version.split_once('-') {
        Some((remainder, release)) => match release.parse::<u64>() {
            Ok(release) => Ok((String::from(remainder), release)),
            Err(_) => Err(VersionParseError::InvalidRelease),
        },
        None => Err(VersionParseError::NoReleaseSpecified),
    }
}

fn compare(lhs: &String, rhs: &String) -> Ordering {
    let l_segments = segments(lhs);
    let r_segments = segments(rhs);

    for (l_segment, r_segment) in l_segments.iter().zip(r_segments.iter()) {
        match compare_segments(l_segment, r_segment) {
            Ordering::Greater => {
                return Ordering::Greater;
            }
            Ordering::Less => {
                return Ordering::Less;
            }
            _ => {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    l_segments.len().cmp(&r_segments.len())
}

fn segments(version: &String) -> Vec<String> {
    normalize(version)
        .split(".")
        .map(|segment| String::from(segment))
        .collect()
}

fn normalize(version: &String) -> String {
    version
        .chars()
        .map(|chr| if chr.is_alphanumeric() { chr } else { '.' })
        .collect()
}

fn compare_segments(lhs: &str, rhs: &str) -> Ordering {
    let l_blocks = blocks(lhs);
    let r_blocks = blocks(rhs);
    let mut last: usize = 0;

    for (index, (l_block, r_block)) in l_blocks.iter().zip(r_blocks.iter()).enumerate() {
        last = index;

        match compare_blocks(l_block, r_block) {
            Ordering::Equal => {
                continue;
            }
            ordering => {
                return ordering;
            }
        }
    }

    match l_blocks
        .iter()
        .nth(last + 1)
        .unwrap_or(&String::new())
        .chars()
        .nth(0)
    {
        Some(chr) => {
            if chr.is_ascii_digit() {
                Ordering::Greater
            } else {
                Ordering::Less
            }
        }
        None => match r_blocks
            .iter()
            .nth(last + 1)
            .unwrap_or(&String::new())
            .chars()
            .nth(0)
        {
            Some(chr) => {
                if chr.is_ascii_digit() {
                    Ordering::Less
                } else {
                    Ordering::Greater
                }
            }
            None => Ordering::Equal,
        },
    }
}

fn blocks(segment: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    let mut block = String::new();

    for chr in segment.chars() {
        match block.chars().nth(0) {
            Some(current) => {
                if same_type(&chr, &current) {
                    block.push(chr);
                } else {
                    result.push(block.clone());
                    block.clear();
                    block.push(chr);
                }
            }
            None => {
                block.push(chr);
            }
        }
    }

    if !block.is_empty() {
        result.push(block.clone());
    }

    result
}

fn same_type(lhs: &char, rhs: &char) -> bool {
    lhs.is_ascii_digit() == rhs.is_ascii_digit()
}

fn compare_blocks(lhs: &String, rhs: &String) -> Ordering {
    if lhs == rhs {
        return Ordering::Equal;
    }

    let l_is_number = lhs.chars().all(|chr| chr.is_ascii_digit());
    let r_is_number = rhs.chars().all(|chr| chr.is_ascii_digit());

    if l_is_number && r_is_number {
        compare_alpha(lhs, rhs)
    } else if l_is_number && !r_is_number {
        Ordering::Greater
    } else if !l_is_number && r_is_number {
        Ordering::Less
    } else {
        lhs.cmp(rhs)
    }
}

fn compare_alpha(lhs: &str, rhs: &str) -> Ordering {
    let lhs = lhs.trim_start_matches('0');
    let rhs = rhs.trim_start_matches('0');

    match lhs.len().cmp(&rhs.len()) {
        Ordering::Equal => lhs.cmp(&rhs),
        ordering => ordering,
    }
}
```

`./src/lib.rs`:

```rust
extern crate core;

pub mod version;
```

Comment: How do you expect Rust to determine how to compare arbitrary structs?

Comment: Can you provide some inputs that compare differently with the comparison operators when `Ord` is moved to a derive? I find that hard to believe since `<`, `=`, `>`, etc only use `PartialOrd` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html)) Though, `.cmp()` *will* behave differently than `.partial_cmp()` in that case since the former will be implemented based on the lexical comparison of the fields in-order instead of using your `PartialOrd` implementation.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I expect it to do so as specified in the default implementations derived by the `PartialEq`, `Eq`, `Ord` and `PartialOrd` macros.
@kmdreko Adding the test cases now.

Comment: BTW, your `Ord`/`PartialOrd` impl can be greatly simplified with [`Ordering::then_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then_with). Also, if your type is `Ord`, you should probably create that impl manually, then call into `cmp` from `partial_cmp`, not the other way around.

Comment: @PitaJ As I said, I've tried this with the result that it changes the behaviour. Regarding the simplification, I will also post this to CR, once I know how to correctly implement the traits.

Comment: I'm was not talking about using the derive macros. They will implement a "unknown" implementation, probably based on field order. I'm talking about calling `.cmp()` in your `partial_cmp` function instead of how you have it now.

Comment: BTW, there's a [clippy lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#derive_ord_xor_partial_ord) advising against this very thing.

Comment: Interesting, since my version of cargo-clippy does not complain about the current implementation. At any rate, my problem, as I stated, is that if I only implement one or the other, the behaviour of the comparison breaks. So, if you have a solution to that, I'm looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Do you mean when you only implement one and `derive` the other? As _I_ said, `derive(Ord)` doesn't make use of an existing `PartialOrd` implementation, or vice versa. The `derived` version that's auto-generated likely has a different order and precedence of fields than yours does. To "fix" it, you'll have to call into `partial_cmp` from `cmp` like you already have, OR do the reverse as I suggested. I just tried it with your code [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e130bcbb984d895b9fc0c67e7435c49) and all tests pass.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can test it for yourself, I posted the entire project including the test cases. Or clone it from [GitHub](https://github.com/conqp/librucman).
If I implement `Ord`, `PartialOrd` has to be implemented as well.
That means, either I do that manually, which means I *have* to implement `partial_cmp()` anyway or I derive it and break the test cases, because the derived implementation does stuff, that I don't understand. Which I want to do. Hence this entire post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://play.rust-lang.org/ to have a look at the expanded macros (Tools -> Expand macros).

The auto implementation for `PartialOrd` is:

```rust
#[automatically_derived]
impl ::core::cmp::PartialOrd for Version {
    #[inline]
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Version)
        -> ::core::option::Option<::core::cmp::Ordering> {
        match ::core::cmp::PartialOrd::partial_cmp(&self.epoch, &other.epoch)
            {
            ::core::option::Option::Some(::core::cmp::Ordering::Equal) =>
                match ::core::cmp::PartialOrd::partial_cmp(&self.version,
                        &other.version) {
                    ::core::option::Option::Some(::core::cmp::Ordering::Equal)
                        =>
                        ::core::cmp::PartialOrd::partial_cmp(&self.release,
                            &other.release),
                    cmp => cmp,
                },
            cmp => cmp,
        }
    }
}
```

and for `Ord`:

```rust
#[automatically_derived]
impl ::core::cmp::Ord for Version {
    #[inline]
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Version) -> ::core::cmp::Ordering {
        match ::core::cmp::Ord::cmp(&self.epoch, &other.epoch) {
            ::core::cmp::Ordering::Equal =>
                match ::core::cmp::Ord::cmp(&self.version, &other.version) {
                    ::core::cmp::Ordering::Equal =>
                        ::core::cmp::Ord::cmp(&self.release, &other.release),
                    cmp => cmp,
                },
            cmp => cmp,
        }
    }
}
```

This explains, why the (actually sane) default implementations break my test cases.

To prevent this, I will wrap the `version` string in a custom `struct` and implement `cmp()` for *it*. This should solve my issue.